# How to create login for a specific form in ms access database

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am looking for a way to create a login access to a specific MS Access form. I have multiple forms in the ms access database but one of the forms must be visible to only one particular user. To this particular form in MS Access I want to create a login window. Any help to create such functionality is much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement an additional form in the Microsoft Access database and manage its visibility depending on the user's authentication status. Additionally, I would apply security measures, such as locking the project to prevent unauthorized access to the VBA code.

```
Private Sub LoginButton_Click()
     ' check user name from your user DB
    username = DLookup("yourUsernameField", "yourUserTable", "[yourUsernameField] = '" & Forms!yourLoginForm!TextBox & "'")
    
    If username =  Forms!yourLoginForm!TextBox   Then
        ' Replace From with the name of the form you want to restrict access to
        DoCmd.OpenForm "formForResticted" 
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "formForNormal""
    End If
End Sub
```